# Android | Load different layout based on a shared Preference value

Tags: android, android-layout, sharedpreferences, android-resources

Does anyone know if it's possible to load different resource (for example layout) based on a shared preference value?

For example let's say we have a list preference with options:

- Large
- Medium
- Small

Is it possible to configure android to load the resource from the respective folder? For example:

layout-Large/main.xml
layout-Medium/main.xml

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Let's be more specific about what i want to do. Let's say i have a application for photo display. I display the images in a gridView with a specific resolution i.e. 150x110. I want to give the option to my user to configure this size by selecting by 3 possible options:

- Large -> (150x110)
- Medium -> (110x90)
- Small -> (90x70)

For this reason a use a preference list with key: let's say 'display.photo.size'.

I want android automatically selected layouts based on this key. For example if user selected Large i want android to selected resources by the folder:

layout-largePhotos

instead of layout folder.

and so on for the other selections.

Comment: are you talking about screen sizes? the layout folder suffix are used internally by Android system, if you want to force your own method of configuration, then you would have to make your foldering system or your file naming system.

Comment: It has nothing to do with screen size. I just want to load different android resources based on a preference value. It could be a values/string or layout.

Check
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

to see what i mean.

Comment: the `res` folder content is strictly controlled by Android, you can't have your own custom folders there. and that follows by saying, no you cannot select which folder the OS is going to select the files from (ie. force `layout-large` over `layout-small`). If you do wish to have custom selection, then you would need to create your files inside the `assets` folder and manage the selection as you wish. OR put the files inside the `res/layout` with different names and select from there.

Comment: Hello?! Are you still there?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was wrong, it is possible to force select the state of the device, but keep in mind that those folders are meant for android to select based on the device configuration.

```
Configuration config = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
config.screenLayout = Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL;
getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Which would force selecting of layouts in the folder `layout-small`, and `config.densityDpi` for the screen density.

Your comment said that the selection you want is not based on screen sizes, if so, then I would recommend, creating the different layout files with appended qualifiers inside the `layout` folder (ie. `main_activity_large.xml`) and make the assignment from there.

Cheers